# Image fallback in canvas with Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, raphael, fallback

I have to draw some images (using a for cycle) and I want to load a fallback image if it can't find the right image.

My javascript:

```
var image = paper_layer.image(image_selected, x, y, width, height);
$('image').one('error', function () {    
    console.log('image not found')
    image_selected='/my_path/not_found.png'
    var image = paper_layer.image(image_selected, x, y, width, height);
});
```

The problem is that when miss an image this function add an fallback image for each image, even the ones found.

I tried this too but it doesn't works (no fallback appears, the message `'image not found'` don't appear on console):

```
var image = paper_layer.image(image_selected, x, y, width, height);
image.onerror=function () {
    console.log('image not found')
    image_selected='/my_path/not_found.png'
    var image = paper_layer.image(image_selected, x, y, width, height);
};
```

PS: I'm using Raphael

Comment: `paper_layer.image` does not return an HTMLImageElement object, but some sort of Raphael object, which however seems to contain the reference to the actual image element under the key 0 - so try `image[0].onerror=...`

Comment: Now it's working, thank you!

Comment: Ok, great, added this as a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paper_layer.image` does not return an HTMLImageElement object, but some sort of Raphael object.

That however seems to contain the reference to the actual image element under the key 0 - so try `image[0].onerror=...`, that should correctly bind the error handler to the actual HTML image element.